# BeanIO - how to write so user can download a file not saved to the server

Tags: java, aws-lambda, bean-io

To get a full idea, the project consists of a webpage with a download button that, when clicked, downloads a text file to the users computer. The webpage uses Javascript and PHP, which will call a Java AWS-Lambda function. The java grabs text from a database.

Originally, I had it working locally as so:

```
StreamFactory sf = StreamFactory.newInstance();
sf.loadResource("mapping.xml");
File file = new File("C:\\test.txt");
BeanWriter bw = sf.createWriter("export", file);

// beans written bellow
...
bw.write(recordName, bean);
```

However, due to the nature of using Lambda functions, I can't as easily save to the server as I could save to my local (would require SSH-ing in programatically, etc). In addition, my senior requested that I make my project not have to save files to the server, so we don't have to manage deleting them later.

I've now been attempting to do it like this:

```
StreamFactory sf = StreamFactory.newInstance();
sf.loadResource("mapping.xml");
OutputStreamWriter output;
BeanWriter bw = sf.createWriter("export", output);

// beans written bellow
...
bw.write(recordName, bean);
```

I've read that createWriter can use a writer instead of a file, but I don't understand how that could be utilized within the javascript side to download as a file. Currently, the code on that end is simple and looks like this:

```
<a href="http://website.com/location/test.txt"download="test.txt">Download</a>
```

This project is not using servlets. My senior is adament about using AWS-Lambda and writing to a stream. It needs to use BeanIO. Most of the similar questions I've seen do not have these as challenges, so this question shouldn't be closed for being a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge about AWS-Lambda, but googling got me to [Leveraging Predefined Interfaces for Creating Handler (Java)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html), specifically `Example 2: Creating Handler with Stream Input/Output (Leverage the RequestStreamHandler Interface)`. From the article you could then use the `Outputstream` provided by the interface to write your response back to the user.

This would HOPEFULLY trigger something similar to a file download request and then the browser could either display the result or ask the user to save the response as a file on their computer.

Combining that with your code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.beanio.BeanWriter;
import org.beanio.StreamFactory;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;

public class HelloBeanIO implements RequestStreamHandler {

  public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, 
      OutputStream outputStream, 
      Context context) 
      throws IOException {

    StreamFactory sf = StreamFactory.newInstance();
    sf.loadResource("mapping.xml");

    // wrap the supplied OutputStream in a OutputStreamWriter 
    // and set the encoding you prefer
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, 
      StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BeanWriter bw = sf.createWriter("export", writer);

    // beans written bellow
    ...
    bw.write(recordName, bean);
  }
}
```

The important part is that you wrap the `OutputStream` passed into the method with a `OutputStreamWriter`.

There are most likely more things to do to get it working properly, somehow maybe setting the correct mime type for the response could change the behaviour of how the browser handles the response.